# Question marked as inappropriate and closed

Tags: discussion

The following question has been closed and has been marked as inappropriate for this forum.

[Free online study materials and codes for Monte Carlo simulation in statistical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59869/free-online-study-materials-and-codes-for-monte-carlo-simulation-in-statistical)

But this question can be **immensely** helpful to students who work in this field of **Monte Carlo simulation in statistical physics**. For example, a similar and very useful question is this one .. [List of freely available physics books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/list-of-freely-available-physics-books), which was not marked as inappropriate.

There is another user who also opposes the moderator's decision and posted comments in support of the question.

I request you to reconsider your decision.

Thanks.

Comment: This is NOT a forum. It's a Q&A site. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I do not agree with the reference request/books/study material policy here either, but unfortunately nothing can be done about it. [Reference requests](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/358/2751) should in principle be [allowed](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2918/2751) whereas asking for books is absolutely not, but the [definitions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/786/2751) of what is a book or valid reference request are applied in a random and unpredictable manner. Valid reference request questions can get retagged and closed as book requests etc. It is a big shame that serious people are (no longer) allowed to ask for any material to (self) study/research physics of more or less advanced and well localized topics at different levels.

Comment: The actual hindrance of people in accessing any study/research material efficiently prevents them from coming back with some "real" conceptual physics question they could have from making use of the study material (they are denied), too.

Comment: For example I would urgently need an introductary tutorial about the Virasoro Algebra or the light cone quantization as applied in string theory for example, but trying to ask such a thing would be just a waste of time. Now I dont know how I could get hold of such a thing ... :-/

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky so you are really even going to deny the reference requests which should be [allowed](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2918/2751), or I would be able to ask this here ... The policies you and Manishearth persue are becoming more and more unwelcoming and orthogonal to the in principle targetted audience as described in the about. You know very well that students nead material to learn from and researchers have to read papers etc. Many good physicists on the site knowledgable about advanced topics to not visit chat.

Answer (score 8):

The book question has been grandfathered in, that's all. Otherwise such questions are more or less off topic.

Recommendation questions are off topic network wide (some reasons are given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174286/178438) -- basically they have caused problems in the past)

Physics.SE does not try to be a resource for everything useful for physics students. We try to focus on closed-ended, conceptual questions here. You may want to try Quora or a similar website for that question.

Comment: I've deleted a number of unnecessary comments. The discussion could be taken to [chat].